# Получить свойство наследника

Tags: c#

У меня есть абстрактный класс со своими свойствами.

```
abstract class Vihicle
{
    [DataMember]
    protected string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    protected double price { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    protected double maxSpeed { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    protected string year { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    protected string color { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    protected int weight { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    protected int amountGears { get; set; }
```

Есть наследники, у которых несколько своих уникальных свойств.

```
class Car: Vihicle
{
    [DataMember]
    private int amountPassengers;
    [DataMember]
    private string type;
```

Объекты хранятся в списке.
Когда я обращаюсь к объекту из списка и хочу получить свойства, то могу получить только свойства абстрактного класса, а к свойствам наследника достучаться не могу.

```
var car = this.garage.vihicle[listBoxInfo.SelectedIndex];

        textName.Text = car.getName();
        textPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(car.getPrice());
        textMaxSpeed.Text = Convert.ToString(car.getMaxSpeed());
        textYear.Text = car.getYear();
        textColor.Text = car.getColor();
        textWeight.Text = Convert.ToString(car.getWeight());
        textAmountPassenger.Text = car.getAmountPassengers();
```

Как можно решить данный вопрос?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведением типов.

Comment: А конкретней можно?
Привести переменную car к типу класса Car ?
Пробовал, не получается

Comment: Покажите как пробовали, расскажите что не получилось.

Comment: var car = this.garage.vihicle[listBoxInfo.SelectedIndex];

            textAmountPassenger.Text = (Vihicle)car.getAmountPassengers();

Comment: textAmountPassenger.Text = (Car)car.getAmountPassengers();

Comment: Всё, у меня получилось. Не там ставил приведение. Нужно было привести весь объект к типу Сar

Comment: Вот и хорошо 